# Enabling Sites in an older Developer Edition Org

Tags: force.com-sites, developer-edition

My Developer Edition org doesn't have **Sites** as an option under Setup | Develop.

[image: No Sites Option]

Is this something that I can get enabled with a case to support, or am I better off starting a new developer org?

My org is cira 2007.

I found the post [Enable SITES to Developer Edition Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000099f3IAA), which makes it look like I'll need to get a new Org:

> Thank you for contacting Salesforce technical support! My name is Ana and I have recently taken ownership of your case.
>
> I understand that you are requesting to have sites enabled for your developer edition. Unfortunately, your developer account was created before sites existed as a Salesforce feature. I am afraid but we cannot enable sites for your developer account.
>
> We really apologize, I understand that you wanted to utilize this org as much as possible, having a fair amount of "tutorial" work done on it. But I have exhausted all my resources to see if there is a work around, the only recommendation to have sites is to create a brand new Dev account with all the recent features included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I used to work in Support at Salesforce, we would process this type of requests but that was a long time ago. I think they have changed the process and you will most likely be advised to sign up for a new org.

---

Excerpts from correspondence between Daniel and support (Case Number: 10659458):

- *Daniel*: My dev org was created in 2007. It does not have access to the Sites feature under Setup > Develop > Sites.
  Can this feature be enabled for my Org?
- *Support*: ..."This could be enable but this would require a license purchase and would require your Account Executive (AE) assistance." ...
  "Please let us know if would like to have an AE assigned to you and reach out to you to discuss about your request. Looking forward to your response."
- *Daniel*: This is a Developer Edition org. I don't have an Account Executive for it or any paid licenses. Is this required, or can I just have the feature enabled?
  If I do require an AE, can you please assign one to me?
- *Support*: This email is to notify you that I'm currently I'm just waiting for our Sales team to assign you an Account Executive (AE). You mentioned that you are using a Developer edition. I have gathered information about your inquiry. Below are the details:
  **Description**
  You have signed up for a Salesforce.com trial organisation.
  The trial organisation does not contain any site.com functionality.
  You require access to the site.com product.
  **Resolution**
  The Technical Support team do not have the ability to enable this feature on trial orgs.
  The easiest way to access a site.com trial is to sign up for a specific site.com trial org here: http://www.site.com/free-trial
  Alternatively, you can sign up for a free Developer Edition org at developer.force.com
  Otherwise, to enable on an existing trial org, contact your Sales Representative and ask them to provision the feature for your trial org. This process may take some time.
  For more information about your inquiry you may refer to this link:
  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-can-I-access-or-enable-a-trial-for-site-com&language=en_US
  Once I receive feedback from our Sales team I will let you know. Have a nice day and thank you for choosing Salesforce.
- *Daniel*: Just to clarify, my Org is already a Developer Edition Organization. It is not a Salesforce.com trial org.
  I'd prefer not to signup for another developer edition org to get access to a feature. I use my current developer org as my main login to forums, dreamforce, etc...
- *Support*: The best work around for your issue is indeed sign up for a new Developer instance. In that way you can keep your existing Developer and with the new Developer instance that you will be getting is for testing purposes. Since the other option was reaching out to your Account Executive (AE) and there is no assign AE yet in your existing Developer instance.

Comment: Thanks. I might try raising the support case just to see what is currently possible and report back with the results in a few days.